# Number Of Uncompleted Tic Tac Toe Games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I want to create a dataset of Tic Tac Toe games, in order to feed it into a machine learning algorithm and create a Tic Tac Toe Engine. Assuming that we have a **3 by 3** board, I want the dataset to contain:

1. All the possible uncompleted games, so in all board states in the dataset, will be at least one empty square (Up to 8 empty squares).
2. I want to keep the rotated duplicate boards.
3. So the only types of games that wont be in the dataset are completed games, and invalid games, where it continues to play even if someone wins.

I created a software that computes this, and got 294777 different games. Is that number right? And regarding if it's right or wrong, how do we compute the number mathematically?

Comment: Do you care about the order in which events occurred?  Or only the board state.  There is an upper bound of $3^9=19683$ board states, so if you were only counting board states your attempted solution came back way too large.  Otherwise, if you did care about order of events, there is an upper bound of $9!=362880$ different games (assuming X always goes first), so your number sounds reasonable

Comment: I want all uncompleted games to be included, meaning that a game with one square filled and all of other squares empty will be included. Games, with 2, 3, ... , 8 filled squares will be included as well. Except for invalid games, and games that ended (draw, X wins, O wins) .

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.  You have yet to define what constitutes a "game."  Does the game where X begins by playing the top left corner, then O playing the middle then X playing the top right corner count as the same game or a different game than the one where X starts with the top *right* corner instead?

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry didn't get you at the beginning. It is different yeah, the first move were X plays top right corner is considered a 'game', then when O plays center, so you have X at top right and O in center is a second game, and so on...

Comment: And yeah X always goes first...

Comment: @AmeerTaweel It is still not clear. Consider the following two boards: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}x & & \\ \hline & o & \\ \hline & & \end{array}$$ and $$\begin{array}{c|c|c} & & x \\ \hline & o & \\ \hline & & \end{array}$$ After the next move ($x$ in top right corner for the first game or $x$ in top left corner for the second game) the two boards are identical: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}x & & x \\ \hline & o & \\ \hline & & \end{array}$$ Are these two identical board configurations considered different games?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe No they are the same game.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel then there are considerably fewer games to consider than what your code calculated. As JMoravitz calculated, an upper bound is $3^9=19,683$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm and http://www.mathrec.org/old/2002jan/solutions.html show there are $255168$ possible completed games (before symmetries reduce this to perhaps $26830$) but there will be fewer board positions

The numbers on those sites can easily be transferred to incomplete games, so your number of incomplete games of $294777$ is in a sense almost correct.  It is made up of

```
     9 incomplete games with 1 move
    72 incomplete games with 2 moves
   504 incomplete games with 3 moves
  3024 incomplete games with 4 moves
 13680 incomplete games with 5 moves
 49392 incomplete games with 6 moves
100224 incomplete games with 7 moves
127872 incomplete games with 8 moves
```

though I think you should also add in

```
     1 incomplete game  with 0 moves
```

Even before symmetries, this overstates the number of positions:

- for example there are only $252$ positions after $3$ moves ($38$ taking account of symmetries), all incomplete
- overall there are $4520$ incomplete positions and $958$ completed positions ($627$ incomplete positions and $138$ completed positions taking account of symmetries)

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the game with the no moves, and then edited the code to not include duplicates, and I got exactly 4520 games.

Comment: Just to make sure my implementation is right, on a 2x2 board, I get 17 games. Is that right?

Comment: @AmeerTaweel for $2 \times 2$ I get $1$ incomplete game  with $0$ moves, $4$ incomplete games  with $1$ move, and $12$  incomplete games  with $2$ moves, making $17$ incomplete games.  There are also $24$ complete games  with $3$ moves

Comment: Cool, then my implementation is working correctly, since I don't want complete games